# How to press F1 for BIOS without keyboard (PS/2 port broken)

Tags: keyboard, bios, ps2-keyboard

A friend of mine has an old PC on which the PS/2 port is broken. After resetting the BIOS a "Press F1 to continue" prompt has blocked us from keep going.

The PS/2 port is broken and the USB ports are disabled after the BIOS reset.

Are there any solutions except buying a new motherboard?

Comment: Though the onboard USB is disabled, what about an USB addon card?

Comment: @kobaltz: we are looking for a cost-less solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a PCI PS/2 card. Only ~$10 on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=pci%20ps/2&_sop=15). Definitely cheaper than getting a new motherboard.

Comment: You got a point there :D